# find a file by metadata using spring GridFsTemplate in MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, gridfs

Can i find a file by metadata  using spring `GridFsTemplate` ?

For example by:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("metadata.target_field", "abcdefg");
```

i find a topic

Is it possible or the best solution is to rewrite the GridFsTemplate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this task in this way.

Mongo `GridFs` create two collections

1. `fs.chunks` where files saved
2. `fs.files` where metadata saved

so i create query using fs.files  structure

```
 Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("metadata.yourdata").is(id));
        query.limit(1);
        query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "uploadDate"));
```

Comment: The ordering wont work: "Returns all files matching the given query. Note, that currently Sort criterias defined at the Query will not be regarded as MongoDB does not support ordering for GridFS file access." 
http://www.javafind.net/library/132/spring-data-mongodb-1.4.0.RC1-javadoc/index.html?org/springframework/data/mongodb/gridfs/GridFsTemplate.html